# Migrate Perforce Branches to Git Branches

Tags: git, perforce, migrate

In perforce I have different folders with their branches. I want to migrate same branches to git. For example, in ABC folders, there are further branches like Apple, Ball and Cat. I want Apple Ball Cat to be the name of my branches in git. I have tried many methods like

```
git p4 clone --detect-branches
```

but that didn't work. Is there any way so that there will be same branches like in P4 to same as Git ?

Comment: This very point seems to be explained in [this](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-p4#_branch_detection) section of the git p4 man page. *("Because it is difficult to infer branch relationships automatically, a Git configuration setting git-p4.branchList can be used to explicitly identify branch relationships.")*

Comment: @RomainValeri What specific command is used ?

Comment: There's an example there, see `git config git-p4.branchList main:branch1` where `main` and `branch1` are to be replaced by your own mapping.

Comment: @RomainValeri Would It take multiple branches from P4 ? Suppose a folder has many branches, would it take the same ? Also for the multiple repositories. ?

Comment: There's another example with two branches [here also](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-p4#Documentation/git-p4.txt-git-p4branchList).

Comment: @RomainValeri Will it work for multiple repositories ?

Comment: Sorry but I'm just going with the man page here, I'm afraid I'm not the git-p4 expert you need...

Comment: @RomainValeri Just wanted to ask that will it work for multiple perforce files to pushed to git ?